# Get the time duration to type a statement in Android

Tags: android, time, textfield

This a small Android application. I need to calculate the time taken to type a given statement on a text field.

example:

Statement 1 - "Hello World" (Hello World is typed on a text field). I need to track the time user takes to type the above string on the text field. Is there any method to get the duration for that task in android?

Thank you so much in advance :)

Comment: Do some minor searches: search for a callback that detects inputs, and register a start time at first input and register a stop time at each new input.

Answer (score 0):

i'd go with [TextView.OnEditorActionsListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.OnEditorActionListener.html)
the idea is to listen for key pressed events. record first one and "last" one, whatever it means in your case. enter key pressed? "hello world" text entered?